# Subcategories with the same name

Tags: categories

The wordpress codex says that a category and subcategory cannot have the same name, even if the subcategory has a different parent.

I'm going to run into this exact situation and am trying to think of a solution. My categories will be US States > Military Bases > Neighborhoods. The problem is that neighborhoods from different bases may have the same name. Like a subdivision called "Stonebridge" near Shaw AFB and Travis AFB. Apparently this will not work in wordpress.

Can anybody think of a way to structure my categories to get around this limitation?

Thanks,
Casey

Answer (score 2):

Two categories can have the same name (title) as long as they are not both parent (top level) categories and are not both children of the same parent category.

No two categories can have the same nicename (slug). If there is a collision when creating a child category, WordPress will append the slug of the parent to the slug of the newly created child category (child-name-parent-name). If there is a collision when creating a top level category a number will be appended to the end of the slug (category-2).